# how can I get password value in Meteor

Tags: meteor, collections

I want to get an user's password value from users Collection.I can get all Documents except the password.What would cause and
i need check old password When users want to change their password with new.How can I do?

Answer (score 3):

User passwords are safely encoded with bcrypt according to industry best practices. That means you cannot "unencode" them.

If you want users to change their password, use [Accounts.changePassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_changepassword).

If your users have forgotten their passwords, you can use [Accounts.resetPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_resetpassword).

Comment: I need check old password When users want to change their password with new.how can I do?

Comment: @CeyhunTekin: Edit your question and include that.

Comment: @SergioTapia No! Askers should **never** edit their question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. You have answered the question OP asked. If he needs anything else, let him ask a _new question altogether_. Do not get drawn into madness by what's known as "help vampires", some users who just want the solution to their problem and do not care about actually learning/sharing anything. If you have answered the original question but the user needs more, tell him to ask a new question.